# How to create a loop that will make regression models in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

I have data that looks something like this, there is time series data for many species over multiple years.

```
Species    year  x
species1   2000  56
species1   2001  12
species1   2002  40
species2   2000  30
species2   2001  40
species2   2002  50
```

For each species, I would like to create a regression model of x vs year, I would also like to plot each model and find the slope of every trendline. To do this, I suspect I should use some type of loop.

Comment: You've asked a bit too much in this question. If you can't
1) Make a loop for subsets of the data
2) Plot a model
3) find the slope of a trendline

Then they're three different things, and I dare say you can at least find points 2 and 3 very easily already on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution without loops.

```
# some artificial data
set.seed(1)
daf <- data.frame(species = factor(paste0("species", c(rep(1:3, 10)))), 
                  year = rep(2000:2009, 3), x = sample(1:100, 30))

library(dplyr)
library(broom)

lm_fit <- daf %>% group_by(species) %>% 
  do(fit = lm(x ~ year, .))

tidy(lm_fit, fit) # or as.data.frame(tidy(lm_fit, fit)) to get a data.frame

# # A tibble: 6 x 6
# # Groups:   species [3]
# species  term          estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <fct>    <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 species1 (Intercept)   2508       7132       0.352   0.734 
# 2 species1 year        -    1.23       3.56   -0.346   0.738 
# 3 species2 (Intercept) -11250       4128      -2.73    0.0260
# 4 species2 year             5.64       2.06    2.74    0.0256
# 5 species3 (Intercept)    461       7460       0.0618  0.952 
# 6 species3 year        -    0.206      3.72   -0.0554  0.957 

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(daf, aes(x = year, y = x)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~species)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're just using `lm` the trick is to change the data argument to subset to something different.

```
speciesList <- unique(df$Species)

for(i in 1:length(speciesList){

    lmmodel <- lm(x ~ year, data = subset(df, Species == speciesList[i]))

    #Now do all the stuff you want with lmmodel, e.g. plot, find slope, etc
}
```

I'm not going to write a whole piece of functional code for you, but that's the tricky bit. There's plenty of resources on how to plot data from models, including trend lines etc.

Using the `subset` function allows us to pull out the subset of our data one species at a time. I got the species list using `unique` and then just step through that element by element.

I also wasn't sure if `x` or `year` was your independent variable, so I made the logical assumption it was `year`.